# Calculating vector when magnitude changes

Tags: vector-spaces

If I have a velocity vector $(4, 5, 2)$ its magnitude is $\sqrt{45}=6.7$ m/s

Now if this object slows down to $3 \ m/s$

Would the new velocity vector be $(4, 5, 2)\cdot\left({3\over \sqrt45}\right)$

$=\left(\left({12\over\sqrt45}\right), \left({15\over\sqrt45}\right), \left({6\over\sqrt45}\right)\right)$ ?

Comment: If that is the only change to the vector. If it the direction in which the object is moving also changes then there would be more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice,

Unit vector in the direction of the initial velocity vector $(4i+5j+2k)$  $$\hat{v}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{45}}(4i+5j+2k)$$$$=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}(4i+5j+2k)$$

Now, the magnitude of velocity reduces to $3\ m/s$ but the direction remains same, hence we have new velocity vector $$=3(\hat v)=3\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}(4i+5j+2k)\right)$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(4i+5j+2k)$$

Hence, 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{New velocity vector:}\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(4i+5j+2k)\equiv\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt5}, \frac{5}{\sqrt5}, \frac{2}{\sqrt5}\right)}}$$